# Disable auto-call javascript function from menu

Tags: javascript, html, function, href

I need call JS function from action link, this is my declaration:

```
<li><a href="javascript:myFunc()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;Test</a></li>
```

Problem is that, function is calling on page load, and i do not know why. Any ideas?

Comment: can you make a fiddle out of this, maybe then someone can help?

Comment: Where is your declaration of myFunc? It might be called in another part of the code, to be sure comment the anchor element and see if it still get called.

Comment: I think that same but not ... i have fnc declaration out of ready block, and one calling is here in menu

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9v9a3r0b/ ... but it is weird... I have that same code in visual studio where fnc is called on page load ... but here do not work at all

Comment: check this : https://jsfiddle.net/9v9a3r0b/1/

Answer (score 0):

put you javascript in `onClick`

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunc()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp;Test</a></li>
```

Comment: onlick is hitted on load too :/